# Creating a Scalar Function in SQL-Server To get Stock Preview

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-server-2008

So I'm having trouble creating a function to get a Preview of the stock of a product.

Simplified Model explanation:
My database has a table of Products, Sales and Orders, and I need to create a function that receives as parameter the Product's NumberID and a date, and return the preview stock on that specific date.
Basically if I have in store 5 bottles, and have an order for tomorrow of 3 bottles, given the 'day after tomorrow' date, then the Stock Preview will be 2.

My problem is, given a date before the current one, I think I'll need to go and see the sales between that date and now and add them to the preview right? and only after that I'll check the orders table.

I've been using many if's and cursors and it's driving me crazy

Comment: Please provide some sample data of your tables..

Comment: Using cursors inside a scalar function is a performance timebomb. Both of those are notoriously horrible for performance. When used together the performance drops exponentially. Sadly nobody can even pretend to help here because you have not provided any details. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.